MySQL- Automatically updating all ranks when new rows are inserted
I have table named 'marks' with following columns- 'roll_number', 'total_marks', 'rank'.
CREATE TABLE marks (
    roll_number INT PRIMARY KEY,
    total_marks DECIMAL(10, 2) DEFAULT 0,
    rank INT DEFAULT 0
);

Explanation:-
I want that whenever values are inserted in 'roll_number', 'total_marks' columns then based on 'total_marks', 'rank' column should be updated with recalculated rank for all rows.
when first entry is made in table
Suppose when first student with roll_number- 101 and total_marks- 130 is inserted then in 'rank' column, '1' should be automatically inserted as he is the only student and no other students data exist in our table.



roll_number
total_marks
rank




101
130
1



when more than one entry
When second student with roll_number- 102 and total_marks- 140 is inserted then 'rank' column for each row needs to be updated with newly calculated rank. Thus, corresponding to roll_number- 102, '1' should be inserted in 'rank' column as now he is the highest scorer and for roll_number- 101, '2' should be automatically inserted in 'rank' column.



roll_number
total_marks
rank




101
130
2


102
140
1



when some students have same total_marks
If some students have scored same 'total_marks' then in that case all those students should get same rank.



roll_number
total_marks
rank




101
130
2


102
140
1


103
130
2



Similarly each time a new student data is inserted in 'roll_number' and 'total_marks' column then fresh 'rank' should be calculated and all students should be assigned with new rank which should automatically be inserted in 'rank' column.
To do this i used MySQL trigger as i wanted that recalculated rank to be automatically inserted in 'rank' column based on marks in 'total_marks' columns. Please note that in 'rank' column recalculated rank should be automatically inserted. I don't want view. I want automatic insertion.
First Code that i tried
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER assign_rank_before_insert
BEFORE INSERT ON marks
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    -- Calculate the rank for the new row
    SET NEW.raw_rank = (
        SELECT COUNT(*) + 1 
        FROM (SELECT DISTINCT total_raw_marks FROM marks) AS ranks 
        WHERE total_raw_marks >= NEW.total_raw_marks
    );

    -- Update ranks for all existing rows
    UPDATE marks
    SET raw_rank = raw_rank + 1
    WHERE total_raw_marks < NEW.total_raw_marks;
END //

DELIMITER ;

After creating this trigger, when i inserted data in 'roll_number' and 'total_marks' column then i got following error- #1442 - Can't update table 'marks' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.
2nd Code that i tried- Combination of Stored Procedure and Trigger by creating temporary table
Stored Procedure
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateRanks()
BEGIN
    -- To Create a temporary table to hold the updated ranks
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_ranks AS
        SELECT total_raw_marks, raw_rank
        FROM marks;

    -- Then Update ranks for all rows using the temporary table
    UPDATE marks m
    JOIN tmp_ranks t ON m.total_raw_marks = t.total_raw_marks
    SET m.raw_rank = t.raw_rank + 1
    WHERE m.total_raw_marks < (SELECT MAX(total_raw_marks) FROM marks);

    -- To Drop the temporary table
    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_ranks;
END //

DELIMITER ;

Trigger
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER assign_rank_before_insert
BEFORE INSERT ON marks
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    -- To Calculate the rank for the new row
    SET NEW.raw_rank = (
        SELECT COUNT(*) + 1 
        FROM (SELECT DISTINCT total_raw_marks FROM marks) AS ranks 
        WHERE total_raw_marks >= NEW.total_raw_marks
    );

    -- Calling the stored procedure to update ranks
    CALL UpdateRanks();
END //

DELIMITER ;

While inserting new data, i got same following error- #1442 - Can't update table 'marks' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.

This task cannot be solved by the trigger because it may need to update the row other than inserted one which is not allowed. The best option - do not store your rank, calculate it in retrievind query. Possible solution - use not INSERT query but stored procedure call which inserts the row then recalculates your data.

You said you don't want a view (or I assume otherwise calculate the rank as Akina suggests), but it's still true that a trigger cannot UPDATE the same table for which the trigger fired. You must UPDATE the ranks from your client application, after you INSERT or DELETE rows. Not from a trigger, but as a subsequent SQL statement. You may use a stored procedure to do this as well, but as a rule I don't recommend using stored procedures in MySQL.
